# What to call someone whose partner is dead

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any particular word for a person whose partner (love) has passed away? Like he/she is keeping lonely now, crying or silent all the time because they miss their dead partner.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***Bereaved***

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bereaved): (of a person) greatly saddened at being deprived by death of a loved one

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bereaved): suffering the death of a loved one

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/bereaved): people who are sad because someone close to them has died

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bereave): be deprived of a loved one through a profound absence, especially due to the loved one’s death

*"Just because we're bereaved doesn't make us saps!" - Walter, The Big Lebowski*

Comment: Similarly, the archaic yet bittersweet-sounding *bereft*.

Answer (score 27):

Possibly a **widow**.

> **widow**
>
> a woman who has lost her spouse by death and has not remarried

*Source: Dictionary.com*

As Hugh mentioned below, a **man** who has lost his wife and not remarried would be a **widower**.

> **widower**
>
> a man who has lost his spouse by death and has not remarried

*Source: Dictionary.com*

Comment: ...and a man who has lost his wife is *a* *widower.*

Comment: I thought that if you were widowed it was a permanent condition. See [Wikipedia - widow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widow). If someone becomes a widow, remarrying doesn't alter that fact.

Comment: @NickGammon - depends on the context. Legally, if you remarry, you're, well, married and not widowed. It's important for things like taxes.

Comment: Or you could opt for the unisex adjective, *widowed*.