# What do you call someone whose unmarried partner has died?

Tags: single-word-requests, interpersonal-relations

What would you call someone whose  unmarried partner has passed away? If they were married, the word would be widow(er). Ex-partner/ex-boy/girlfriend doesn't seem to fit either because the two never broke up, except their partner is dead so they aren't technically together anymore.

Comment: The mourning partner/life companion/soul mate.... I've also heard of "surviving partner" especially in cases where one half of the couple lost their life in an accident. Online I found [*surviving civil partner*](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/social_welfare/social_welfare_payments/death_related_benefits/widows_contrib_pension.html)

Comment: 'The bereaved'.

Comment: Bereavement is as generic as grieving, which is what they're doing: *grieving the loss of their significant other*.

Comment: Or 'the relict'.

Comment: Depends on the relationship. If they’ve only been going out for two weeks and are in a fairly casual relationship, even _surviving partner_ doesn’t sound right to me (I’d probably just go with _boy-/girlfriend_). If they’d been living together in a paperless marriage for a generation, I would have absolutely no hesitation in calling the bereaved partner a _widow(er)_.

Comment: Shouldn't most of these comments be answers?

Comment: The root problem is, linguistically (or legally), unmarried partners aren't really *anything at all*. There's no distinction between deep partnerships and a club hookup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to call someone whose partner is dead](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259268/what-to-call-someone-whose-partner-is-dead)

Comment: @Harper What? They're "partners." That's distinct from a random person. I don't know of anyone who would call a club hookup a "partner."

Comment: @R. The problem with that is that two-word answers automatically go into the Very Low Quality review queue, from where some idiots invariably vote to them. Their system: my solution.

Comment: @user207421: I agree this site has problems like that, but you could write a bit more about example usage, why it's right, give a citation, etc..

Comment: Depending upon the legal jurisdiction and how long they cohabited, they could be considered married by [Common-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-law_marriage), in which case "widowed" would be appropriate.  The real question is how the bereaved person *wants* to be known.

Comment: I say again, this is absolutely NOT a question for ELL.

Answer (score 75):

There's no word with the specific meaning of a person who has lost a girlfriend or boyfriend, but you can use the word **[bereaved](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bereaved)**. This can be used for the loss of anyone close, including close friends and other family members.

Normally this is used when the death was relatively recent, and the person is still suffering from the loss.

> "The bereaved will need the support of her friends during this
>   difficult time."

Comment: I agree with this answer, though I'd note that "bereaved" connotes (to me, at least) that the two had been together in a long-term relationship equivalent to a marriage, which I think is the context of the OP.   *Surviving partner* (mentioned in other comments) is slightly more specific but otherwise equivalent.  Both are relatively formal.  If it were just a casual short-term relationship, I would just use "boy/girlfriend".

Comment: @Richter65 I disagree that it has any such connotation. As evidence, airlines offer *bereavement fares* to what I would call extended family members. Delta helpfully provides a [list of relationships](https://www.delta.com/us/en/special-circumstances/bereavement-fares) that can qualify as "bereaved" for the purpose of special airfare.

Comment: @No U: that's why "surviving partner" is more specific; "bereaved" only connotes a close relationship.  But in the context in the OP, that relationship is a partner, and therefore (to me) *bereaved* connotes a long-term "married in all but name" relationship in this particular situation.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't any word that specifically means "person whose boyfriend/girlfriend died." So you compromise.

Comment: "Bereaved" to me also connotes a relatively recent loss, though I guess that isn't inherent in the definition.

Comment: Guys it does not help to give answers to questions that should just be migrated to the learner's list.   This QA is about 18 miles away from the purpose of this site.

Comment: @Fattie this is hardly an ELL question.

Comment: 'cue :  fair enough, have to disagree (note the close votes).

Answer (score 7):

**Survivor**.  Source: [WordWeb](https://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SURVIVOR).  *Surviving partner*, as Mari-Lou A says, would be  a more formal version.

Comment: This is correct, but also likely subject to misinterpretation. My first assumption when hearing the person spoken of this way would be that *both partners* were involved in a potentially fatal situation of some sort (car crash, etc.) and that only one of them survived. *Surviving partner* actually sounds less misdirecting here.

Comment: @R. I disagree that this is correct. I don't think many (or possibly _any_) people would use "survivor" for this. It will always require clarification unless a lot of context is provided. Hard to believe it got so many upvotes...

Comment: +1 This answer is correct, however it is INCREDIBLY formal, and usually used to refer to family.  This would be common in an obituary, but definitely not in casual conversation.

Comment: Incorrect - a survivor of a deceased implies a decedent. If two people are not part of the same family tree (married or not) the deceased is only "survived" through any offspring. This is an issue dealing with genetics, not memory and most people do not comprehend that context.

Answer (score 4):

Colloquially, I have heard widow(er) being used for long-standing unmarried relationships just as well as for married ones. The significance of official marriage in regards to everyday language seems to have declined quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather archaic (I've only ever seen it used on tombstones), but *relict* was also used for 'common law' widows/widowers as well as legally married ones.