# If you lost your signifcant other or a partner, but you weren't married, are you still a widow/widower or what is the correct term?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you dated someone and lived together, built family and had kids for e.g. 10 years or more, but you weren't married, they weren't your spouse, what does that make you when they pass away?

Definition on Wikipedia says:

> A widow is a woman whose spouse has died and a widower is a man whose
> spouse has died.

I'm a foreigner and I can't figure this out, what is the correct word, is it still widow/widower?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call someone whose unmarried partner has died?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/517596/what-do-you-call-someone-whose-unmarried-partner-has-died)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not a widow or widower, because you were not married.

You are bereaved (verb) or “the bereaved” (noun).

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/bereaved

Comment: So if someone say 'I'm a widow/widower', you don't really say 'I'm a bereaver'?

Comment: Widows and widowers are also bereaved, or the bereaved, at least for a while.

Comment: Sure, they’re bereaved too. Some of them. They’re also called bereaved in press accounts and funeral and memorial services, whether or not they are bereaved.

Comment: @user3108268 No, you don’t say I’m a bereaver. You say he/she was a dear friend and I’m very sad, and I will miss him/her greatly. You could say “We were partners” or “partners in life.”